# Convert a list of NumPy np.uint8 arrays to a np.unicode_ array

Tags: python, string, numpy, unicode

I have a list of NumPy variably-sized arrays with `dtype=np.uint8`(these represent UTF-8 encoded strings). How do I efficiently and fast convert this list to a single `dtype=np.unicode_` array?

```
l = [np.frombuffer(b'asd', dtype = np.uint8), np.frombuffer(b'asdasdas', dtype = np.uint8)]

# The following will work, but will first create a temporary string which is inefficient. 
# I'm looking for a method that would directly allocate a target np.unicode_-typed array 
# and encode the data into it.
a = np.array([s.tostring().decode('utf-8') for s in l])
```

The arrays are not just ASCII encoded, they do contain other characters:

```
s = b'8 \xd0\x93\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4 \xd0\x91\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd1\x83\xd1\x80 (\xd0\xa0\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xbf\xd1\x83\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbb ...: \xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 \xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x85\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd)' 

s.decode('utf-8') # works
```

Comment: Provide us with a realistic example of what you want to work with.  That `s=b'8 ...' line is not valid Python.

Comment: `numpy` doesn't do much string processing with its own code,   For example the `np.char.decode` function essentially iterates through the array, applying the `string` method - without much speed up compared to a list iteration.  Your `a` is the fastest thing I've found.

Answer (score 0):

**update**

It turns out Python utf-8 codec can be used to decode
an ndarray directly, without needing to copy its contents
to a bytesstring with `.tostring()` first: with the codecs
module it is possible to retrieve the callable that
coverts utf-8 byte-sequences to unicode strings without
having to go through `str.decode`

```
lst = [np.frombuffer(b'asd', dtype = np.uint8), np.frombuffer(b'asdasdas', dtype = np.uint8)]

import codecs

decoder = codes.getdecoder("utf-8")    
data = np.array([decoder(item)[0] for item in lst], dtype="unicode")
```

This avoids one step of the conversion - there is another step that could
be avoided, because this will still create a list of all strings in memory
before calling the last `.array` constructor - numpy has a `.fromiter` array constructor - but it can't create an array with arbitrary unicode objects - it needs a fixed character width. That would end up consuming more memory than you are so far:

```
data = np.fromiter((decoder(item) for item in lst), count=len(lst), dtype="U120")  # For max-length of 120 characters.
```

**original- answer** (mostly rome rambling)

Modern Python internal handling of Unicode text is quite efficient, with the internal unicode point representation depending on the widest char in a string.

Numpy, on the other side, just stores a 32bit value for each unicode character - and it has no business "understanding" utf-8. The Python language does that very well - and its fast. Although Python won't use any multi-threaded, multi-core, or hardware accelerated strategy when decoding utf-8 bytes to text, the decoding takes place in native code, and is as fast as you will get in a single CPU core.

Decoding a 4MB-sized text to unicode using plain Python just took under 30ms in my system.

In other words: you are getting worried with the wrong problem - unless whatever you are coding needs to convert about 100-bible-sized text corpus per second in a sustained way.

Just let Python do the utf-8 decoding, and handle the result back to numpy (which will encode it again in its 32bit format) - the the spent on this is so negligible for the great majority of real-world tasks that this is the way the Pandas library, for example,  performs almost all of its actions on data: creating new copies of it after each operation.

Comment: I was doing this work as part of implementing a basic TSV parser (that operates on 100k lines with a few string columns) - I do this because standard parsers work quite slow in Mozilla Pyodide. I can do number parsing (from a uint8 array) faster than csv.reader + conversion. The string array construction is currently the bottleneck and takes twice more time than number conversion. Ideally I'd like to construct the final column array from just [(begin, end), ...] character index pairs

Comment: Maybe you can store the strings already decoded instead of having them in utf-8 in disk?

Comment: The TSV files may be provided by users, and unfortunately this is not a restriction we want to impose.

Comment: Yes - that would imply processing your input earlier in the pipeline, in another process, so that your cpu intensive task do not have to deal with it. Anyway, it does seem that you *do* match the demand I predicted of "several bibles/sec"? 
Can you tell if you have idle cores in this translation process? I could come up with another answer with a parallel approach to that.